# What is happening to my output? (Am I using "Is Nothing" correctly?)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web form that may or may not result in blank answers when it is submitted. To remedy this I wrote a for loop to set each variable that is empty to the string "(blank). However the for loop doesn't return anything.
What is happening to my output? Am I using "Is Nothing" correctly?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Text

Partial Class acen_EarlyIntervention
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Insert Form Values into an array

        Dim strDate As String = "Date: " & Dates.Text
        Dim strStudent As String = "Student: " & Student.Text
        Dim strUin As String = "UIN: " & UIN.Text
        Dim strSContact As String = "Student Contact: " & SContact.Text()

        Dim strCourse As String = "Course: " & Course.Text
        Dim strFaculty As String = "Refering Facilty: " & Refer.Text
        Dim strFContact As String = "Faculty Contact: " & FContact.Text
        Dim strReason As String = "Reasons:" & Reason.Text

        Dim strPContact As String = "Previous Contact: " & Before.Text
        Dim strMContact As String = "Mthod of Contact: " & DropDownList1.Text
        Dim strOMC As String = "Other Method of Contact: " & TextBox8.Text
        Dim strComment As String = "Additional Comments: " & TextBox9.Text
        'Creating email string

        Dim sBodyBuilder As New StringBuilder
        Dim values As String() = {strDate, strStudent, strUin, strSContact, strCourse, strFaculty, strFContact, strReason, strPContact, strMContact, strOMC, strComment}
        For Each item In values
            If item Is Nothing Then
                item = "(blank)"
                sBodyBuilder.AppendLine(item)
            End If
        Next item

        Dim body As String = sBodyBuilder.ToString
```

Comment: item, as used above, will NEVER be `Nothing` as you initialize each variable with a prompt string.  Also, you already HAVE the form variables you don't need reassign them to local variables

Answer (score 2):

Using Is Nothing checks to see if the string reference is not set.  It's the same as checking for null in C#.  What you probably want to do is check if it is an empty string.  Try using [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) Then
```